# Convert userId in lightning app

Tags: apex, javascript, lightning-aura-components

I'm able to assign items to users. What's returned from the database is their Id. How do I convert that Id to their first and last name on my lightning app?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Users in SFDC are Stored in the [User](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_user.htm) Object in salesforce .You will need to query for that Object or write [Relationship queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) in your backend apex controller class for the lightning .

```
[Select Id , User__r.Name from Object__c];//This is an example of relationship query .
```

Comment: I need two user names using two Id. This is what I have so far List<String> userNames2 = [SELECT Name FROM User WHERE Name IN (:whiteboardItemAssignedUserId, :whiteboardItemCompletedUserId)]; but it's not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Post your full lightning code .You should return an User Object via lightning controller and pass array of userIds .Please post all your lightning code so we can help you . Return a wrapper object and you will not need two different server calls

Comment: Shoot, your suggestion is working, but the Id's on the page return null, because they are populated on initialization. Since I'm converting the Id's on initialization, there is noting to convert...

Comment: I'm initializing the page to show items with their associated assigned User Ids. How do I convert them at initialization as well?

Comment: Awesome, I got what you were saying, eventually, :D THANKS!